# When running a queue job in laravel to send email, two processes are generated, how to resolve this and keep only one?

Tags: laravel, email, queue, laravel-8, jobs

When sending an email with queue job in laravel, it creates two processes, why? Is there a way to fix and keep only one? Is there any function that does this? for each dispatch, a single process.

##### Controller

```php
public function sendMail()
{
    $email = "gustavo.gomes@teste.com.br";
    SendMail::dispatch($email);

    return view('site.email-enviado');    
}
```

##### Job

```php
public function handle()
{
    Mail::to('teste@test.com')->queue(new MensagemTesteMail($this->email)); 
}
```

##### Email

```php
public function build()
{
    return $this->subject('gustavocamalionti@gmail.com')
        ->from(env("MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS", null), 'Teste email')
        ->view('emails.cadastro-sucesso');
}
```

`php artisan queue:work`

[image: CLI]

Comment: What is the issue about having 2 jobs?

Comment: by calling dispatch() only once, shouldn't there be only 1 job? I don't understand why it generated these two.

Answer (score 1):

You are not executing 2 processes (job workers)... You only have one...

1. The first one is literally saying it is processing A job (`SendMail`) you have sent to the queue
2. The second line is saying that the `SendMail` job was processed
3. The third one is literally saying it is processing A job (`MensagemTesteMail`) (I recommend a lot to ONLY CODE IN ENGLISH)
4. The fourth one is saying that the `MensagemTesteMail` job was processed

You have 2 jobs, because the first job (`SendMail`) is executing `Mail::to('teste@test.com')->queue(new MensagemTesteMail($this->email));` and that literally creates the Mail (`MensagemTesteMail`). It is a job because you have it as so... You literally have `->queue(new MensagemTesteMail($this->email))`, so that is the second job...

Comment: So what's the solution? I mean obviously he doesn't need the `SendMail` job if `MessageTesteMail` is queueable :)

Comment: So, is it possible to create just one job, in this case, the send email job? instead of generating two?

I have this conceptual problem that is driving me crazy kkkkk

I need that, when the job sends the email, it saves it in a third table in order to create a grid in my system that has the sending status "success, failure, pending".

Comment: I thought of doing it this way: in the job handle, create the record in the third table saving the uuid and other information with pending status, in AppServiceProvder, using Queue::after check if it failed or not, if not failed, update for success status , if it failed, it updated the status to fail.

Comment: It was the solution I found to be able to relate the job or the job_failed (if it happened), with the third table. make an insert with the uuid in a third table when the "handle" is triggered

Comment: @GustavoGomes So to come to terms, you don’t need the `SendMail` job, just use the mailable class and work from there.

Comment: I agree, but I would need to save the uuid of the job because if there is an error in the submission, I can consult this third table and save an exception from the jobs_failed table.

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the uuid (getJobId()), in the mailable?

Comment: I applied queue and job because the idea would be for the user to send several emails and be able to continue discussing in the application.

Comment: @GustavoGomes ofcourse, don’t queue the mail in your job. Send the mail from your Job directly.